# AngularJS - $watch <ul> children length issue

Tags: angularjs, dom, directive, watch

I've the following html list :

```
<input ng-model="searchValue" />
[...]
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in dataset" ng-if="item.contains(searchValue)">{[item.name]}</li>
  <li noresult>No result ...</li>
</ul>
```

I prefer use the ng-if than the ng-repeat filter.

And I want to manage the 'noresult' display with the following directive :

```
directive('noresult', [
    function () {return {
        restrict: "A",
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            function () { return element.parent().children().length; },
            function (length) {
                console.log(length)
                if(length == 1){element.show();}
                else{element.hide();}
            }
          );
        } 
}}]);
```

When I type something into the input, "console.log" raises each two letters !

Why ? And how can I fix it ?

Comment: Why don't you just check the length..? `ng-if="dataset.length===0"`

Comment: Because dataset.length doesn't change.

Comment: What does _"console.log" raises each two letters_ mean?

Comment: If I type only one letter, nothing happend, and on the second the log writes. On the third nothing.. fourth log writes ect...

Comment: Why are you looking at the DOM to show no result. Just check for the data result filtered. _This is not so angular way and you are doing too much just to show no result, your logic in the directive since it needs DOM relies on angular digest cycle_. And it is unclear what you are saying, a demo perhaps?.

Comment: Surely, but there needs to be a solution in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found, adding this to controller:

```
$scope.$watch('searchValue', function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply();
}),1});
```

But it's makeshift job..
I understand that what I wanted to do was ***not The AngularJS Way***.

But, filter's algorithms must be in the object and not just anywhere.
It's ***The Object Way***!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following, without using a directive ?

```
<input ng-model="searchValue" />

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in filteredSet = (dataset | filter:searchValue)" ng-if="showItem(item, searchValue)">{{item}}</li>
  <li  ng-if="filteredSet.length == 0">No result ...</li>
</ul>
```

And add a function in the controller:

```
$scope.showItem = function(item, searchVal) {
    return !searchVal || item.indexOf(searchVal) > -1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9bj24ab/1/)

Comment: Thanks, But I prefer use the ng-if than the ng-repeat filter.